How to setup Ceph with S3 Bucket Encryption using Hashicorp Vault with Ansible?
I stood up a 3-node HA Vault cluster via Ansible playbook I designed. I have a 3-node Ceph cluster environment (Reef) up and running using cephadm (https://computingforgeeks.com/install-ceph-storage-cluster-on-ubuntu-linux-servers/).
Now I need to setup SSE-S3 ceph bucket encryption for the environment using the "transit" engine and RGW Agent way (rgw crypt vault auth = agent), but the instructions given here (https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/vault/) are WAY too confusing as both token and agent configurations are mixed back and forth.
Is there an Ansible playbook available for doing it easier?
